# java.lang.runtimeexception java.net.connectexception while running hadoop pi example

Tags: jakarta-ee, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

i have configured hadoop on two machine. i can access both machine without password using ssh.i have successfully formatted namenode using following command:--

```
bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

then i tried to run pi example which shipped with hadoop.tar

```
sandip@master:~/hadoop-1.0.4$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar pi 5 500
Number of Maps  = 5
Samples per Map = 500
13/04/14 04:13:04 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server:       
master/192.168.188.131:9000. Already tried 0 time(s).
13/04/14 04:13:05 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server:                         
master/192.168.188.131:9000. Already tried 1 time(s).
13/04/14 04:13:06 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server:     
master/192.168.188.131:9000. Already tried 2 time(s).
13/04/14 04:13:07 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server:   
master/192.168.188.131:9000. Already tried 3 time(s).
13/04/14 04:13:08 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server:   
master/192.168.188.131:9000. Already tried 4 time(s).
13/04/14 04:13:09 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server:      
master/192.168.188.131:9000. Already tried 5 time(s).
13/04/14 04:13:10 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server:     
master/192.168.188.131:9000. Already tried 6 time(s).
13/04/14 04:13:11 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server:   
master/192.168.188.131:9000. Already tried 7 time(s).
13/04/14 04:13:12 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server:   
master/192.168.188.131:9000. Already tried 8 time(s).
13/04/14 04:13:13 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server:    
master/192.168.188.131:9000. Already tried 9 time(s).
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Call to    
master/192.168.188.131:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException:    
Connection refused
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getWorkingDirectory(JobConf.java:546)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:318)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.PiEstimator.estimate(PiEstimator.java:265)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.PiEstimator.run(PiEstimator.java:342)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.PiEstimator.main(PiEstimator.java:351)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at     
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at 
 org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at
```

Comment: Have you started the cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ooh M G i forgot to start hadoop cluster. I Fixed it by running this command:-

bin/start-all.sh

Answer (score 0):

It says : Connection refused . 
By seeing log I can say that while starting the cluster, your machine is not able to connect to namenode.

Check following things:
- Name node address is correct ( you give it using default.fs.name in core-site.xml)
- Check if you have specified task tracker's address correct in mapred-site.xml
- Check if you have specified the hadoop.tmp.dir property in core-site.xml. And this directory exists on your machine after formatting.

-After formatting just verify one more thing is VERSION file should contain the same name space ids in master and slave nodes.

Comment: I didn't specify task tracker's address, i specified only job tracker's address in mapred-site.xml. i have specified the hadoop.tmp.dir property in core-site.xml and it also exist in my machine at specified path.and i am getting some folder inside it when running "hadoop start-dfs.sh" command. and sir i want to know how to check version file where it exist