# Yarn UI shows no active node while it appeared in HDFS UI

Tags: hdfs, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I've setup Hadoop in my laptop,
and when I submit a job on Hadoop (though MapReduce and Tez),
the status always ACCEPTED, but the progress always stuck at 0% and description wrote something like "waiting for AM container to be allocated".

When I check the node through YARN UI(localhost:8088),
it shows that the active node is 0

[image]

But from HDFS UI(localhost:50070), it shows that there are one live node.

[image]

Is that the main reason that cause the job stuck since there are no available node? If that's the case, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

In your YARN UI, it shows you have **zero** vcores and **zero** memory so there is no way for any job to ever run since you lack computing resources.  The datanode is only for storage (HDFS in this case) and does not matter as far as why your application is stuck.

To fix your problem, you need to update your yarn-site.xml and provide settings for the memory and vcore properties described in the following:

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/10/untangling-apache-hadoop-yarn-part-2/

You might consider using a Cloudera QuickStart VM or Hortonworks Sandbox (at least as a reference for configuration values for the yarn-site.xml).

https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/quickstart_vms/5-10.html
https://hortonworks.com/products/sandbox/

Comment: Hi, I have follow your answer and able to bring up the node, however I'm still unable carry out any hadoop job successfully.

Comment: How many total vcores and total memory do you now have showing in the YARN UI?  Also, when you say you brought up a node, do you mean a Node Manager?  You'll need that service with YARN to run jobs.

Comment: Yes the node manager is able to bring up successfully now. My laptop has 8GB or RAM and 4 Cores. In yarn-site.xml I set the yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb to 6GB and yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores to 4. Hence in YARN UI it shows 6GB RAM and 4 cores as total.

Comment: Can you run a simple pi job with 1 mapper from hadoop-examples.jar?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998681/java-lang-runtimeexception-java-net-connectexception-while-running-hadoop-pi-exa or https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-4-x/topics/cm_ig_testing_the_install.html#concept_cc2_vcr_bm

Comment: I have the same issue. Has anyone found a solution? I found the following error in my resourcemanager log `Skipping activateApplications for appattempt_1518114056719_0001_000001 since cluster resource is <memory:0, vCores:0>`

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do is check if NodeManager is up and running. If not, then there'll be no active node showing up in Resourcemanager UI.

So, in terminal, run:

```
jps
```

If you don't see NodeManager listed in the result, then run:

```
yarn --daemon start nodenamager
```